# C# ClosedXML Rich text implement in range not in cell

Tags: c#, closedxml

I want to insert rich text in a range of my excel sheet, not in particular cell.

for eg: I want to insert `ABCDEFGH; IJKLMNOPQ` in a range where AB...H will come in `red` color and IJ....Q will come in `blue` color.
[image]

How will i implement it using closedxml ?

Answer (score 2):

try this please

```
var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sample Sheet");
worksheet.Cell("B2").RichText.AddText("ABCDEFGH; ").SetFontColor(XLColor.Red);
worksheet.Cell("B2").RichText.AddText("IJKLMNOPQ").SetFontColor(XLColor.BabyBlue);
worksheet.Range(worksheet.Cell("B2"), worksheet.Cell("H2")).Merge();
workbook.SaveAs(@"c:\temp\HelloWorld3.xlsx");
```